# ios lock/unlocks count when device is background mode

Tags: ios, ios7, ios5, ios6

I am doing one task which is lock /unlocks count.It is working fine when app is in foreground but it is not working in background.Please help me

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:0 forKey:@"COUNT"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

    isVAlue=0;
    //[self registerAppforDetectLockState];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"kDisplayStatusLocked"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    MainViewController *mainCtrl=[[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController=mainCtrl;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)registerAppforDetectLockState {

    int notify_token,countval;
    NSString *task=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"STATE"];


    notify_register_dispatch("com.apple.springboard.lockstate", &notify_token,dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(int token)
    {

        uint64_t state = UINT64_MAX;

        notify_get_state(token, &state);

        NSLog(@"notify_token %d",token);

        if (isVAlue)
        {
           // notify_cancel(token);
        }


        if(state == 0) {

            isVAlue=YES;
            taskName=@"Unlock";
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:taskName forKey:@"STATE"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

            int value=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"COUNT"]intValue];
            value=value+1;

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:value  forKey:@"COUNT"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
            NSLog(@"value %d",value);

            NSLog(@"unlock device");
            NSDictionary *incrementVal=@{@"incrementVal":[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]};
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HiEverybody" object:self userInfo:incrementVal];




        } else {

            taskName=@"Lock";
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:taskName forKey:@"STATE"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];


            NSLog(@"lock device");
            isVAlue=NO;

        }


    });
}



- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.


    UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        NSLog(@"Sent to background by locking screen");
        [self backgroundTask];

    } else if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"kDisplayStatusLocked"]) {
            NSLog(@"Sent to background by home button/switching to other app");
        } else {

            NSLog(@"Sent to background by locking screen");
            [self backgroundTask];

        }
    }




}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"kDisplayStatusLocked"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    //[self registerAppforDetectLockState];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

}

-(void)backgroundTask
{
    UIApplication*    application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;
    //Registered a background task, telling the system we need to borrow some events to the system
    background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {
        //[self registerAppforDetectLockState];
        //Whether or not complete, the end of background_task task
        [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
        background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [self registerAppforDetectLockState];

        if (TRUE)
        {
            NSLog(@"running");
        }

        [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
        background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

Please help how to run the app in background mode continuously.
Thanks
Dronavalli

Answer (score 0):

> Please help how to run the app in background mode continuously.

This is not possible. You cannot ensure that you app always runs.

*If* the user has launched you, and *if* you haven't been killed yet, and *if* the user has a lock-code, you can implement the `UIApplicationDelegate` methods `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable:` and `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeAvailable:` to find out when data protection is turned on and off, which is a proxy for what you're talking about. But it is unlikely to closely match what you're describing.

As stated, your application cannot be implemented. Apps are not OS services in iOS. You will need to narrow your focus to the actual need.

Comment: Will this delegate be called when app is in background?

Comment: Yes, as long as you're actually running. The `WillBecomeUnavailable` really can *only* happen when you're in the background (since the phone isn't going to lock when you're actively using the app).

Comment: Even if my app is launched by the OS using the significant location updates, I can expect the call back in this method?

Comment: Yes, but I suspect you're thinking about this incorrectly. This method is called at the point that keychain is locked or unlocked, which is unlikely to occur during the fraction of a second that you're likely running after a location update. If you want to know if protected data is *currently* available, use `UIApplication.isProtectedDataAvailable`.

Comment: Please go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115099/ios-most-battery-economic-sensor-data-to-determine-if-the-device-is-being-used

Answer (score -1):

Check out the "Implementing long-running background tasks" section of this doc from Apple.
From Apple's doc: Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks
Support for some types of background execution must be declared in advance by the app that uses them. An app declares support for a service using its Info.plist file. Add the UIBackgroundModes key to your Info.plist file and set its value to an array containing one or more of the following strings: (see Apple's doc from link mentioned above.)